# Is there a way to statically verify that a type implements certain traits?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a library in Rust and I am exposing a type which needs to implement `Send` and `Sync`. In my library, I don't take advantage of the fact that it implements these traits, but my users will. Is there some way to tell the compiler that I need the type to implement these traits, and have it raise a compile error if it doesn't?